# Postman dosent give me expected output

Tags: java, eclipse, postman

this is my pom.xml code and when i run this code it normal compiles and run but when i run it in postman it show  a 500 error.when i remove the dependencies which are shown in the comments which makes 500 error
it makes errors in eclipse project but it runs and  and give the output and it works for the postman too and gives the output for get . when i add the rest 4 dependencies it makes an error. those 4 tokens are needed to me to run the token in my project,

This is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>Hospital</groupId>
      <artifactId>Hospital</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <packaging>war</packaging>
      <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>

            <configuration>
              <source>1.8</source>
              <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
          <artifactId>mevan-war-plugin
          </artifactId>
          <version>3.2.3</version>
          <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          </configuration>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.2</version>
      <configuration>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
            <dependencies>


       <dependency>
     <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.4</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.4</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.1</version>
       </dependency>
    <dependency>
                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
                <version>7.0</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
                <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
                <version>0.7.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.0</version>
    </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    </project>
```

**Error in Postman API-:**

```
      HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
        Type Exception Report

        Message Servlet.init() for servlet [Jersey Web Application] threw exception

        Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

        Exception

        javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet [Jersey Web Application] threw exception
            org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526)
            org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
            org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
            org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
            org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
            org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
            org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860)
            org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587)
            org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
            java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
            java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
            org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
            java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
        Root Cause

        java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
            jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:170)
            jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:153)
            jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:424)
            com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.AnnotationScannerListener.onProcess(AnnotationScannerListener.java:138)
            com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.JarFileScanner.scan(JarFileScanner.java:97)
            com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.servlet.WebAppResourcesScanner$1.f(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:94)
            com.sun.jersey.core.util.Closing.f(Closing.java:71)
            com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.servlet.WebAppResourcesScanner.scan(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:92)
            com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.servlet.WebAppResourcesScanner.scan(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:79)
            com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init(ScanningResourceConfig.java:80)
            com.sun.jersey.api.core.servlet.WebAppResourceConfig.init(WebAppResourceConfig.java:102)
            com.sun.jersey.api.core.servlet.WebAppResourceConfig.<init>(WebAppResourceConfig.java:89)
            com.sun.jersey.api.core.servlet.WebAppResourceConfig.<init>(WebAppResourceConfig.java:74)
            com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.getWebAppResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:668)
            com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.getDefaultResourceConfig(ServletContainer.java:435)
            com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.getDefaultResourceConfig(ServletContainer.java:602)
            com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebServletConfig.getDefaultResourceConfig(WebServletConfig.java:87)
            com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:699)
            com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:674)
            com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:205)
            com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:394)
            com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:577)
            javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
            org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526)
            org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
            org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
            org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
            org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
            org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
            org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860)
            org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587)
            org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
            java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
            java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
            org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
            java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
        Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.

        Apache Tomcat/9.0.24
```

**My code**

```
        package com;
        import model.Hospital;
        //For REST Service
        import javax.ws.rs.*;
        import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
        //For JSON
        import com.google.gson.*;
        //For XML
        import org.jsoup.*;
        import org.jsoup.parser.*;
        import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
        @Path("/Hospital")

        public class HospitalService {
            Hospital h1 = new Hospital();
            @GET
            @Path("/")
            @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)

            public String readHospital() {
                return h1.readHospital();
            }
            @POST
            @Path("/")
            @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
            @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
            public String insertHospital(
                @FormParam("H_name") String H_Name,
                @FormParam("H_contactNumber") String H_Contact_Number,
                @FormParam("H_address") String H_address,
                @FormParam("H_email") String H_email
            ) {
                String output = h1.insertHospital(H_Name, H_Contact_Number, H_address, H_email);
                return output;
            }
            @PUT
            @Path("/")
            @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
            public String updateHopital(String dData) {

                JsonObject h2 = new JsonParser().parse(dData).getAsJsonObject();
                String H_ID = h2.get("H_ID").getAsString();
                String H_Name = h2.get("H_name").getAsString();
                String H_contactNumber = h2.get("H_contactNumber").getAsString();
                String H_address = h2.get("H_address").getAsString();
                String H_email = h2.get("H_email").getAsString();


                String output = h1.updateHopital(H_ID, H_Name, H_contactNumber, H_address, H_email);
                return output;
            }
            @DELETE
            @Path("/")
            @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
            @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
            public String deleteHospital(String dData) {

                Document doc = Jsoup.parse(dData, "", Parser.xmlParser());


                String H_ID = doc.select("H_ID").text();
                String output = h1.deleteHospital(H_ID);
                return output;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Could it be a typo in pom.xml: `<artifactId>mevan-war-plugin`?  It has to be `<artifactId>maven-war-plugin`

Comment: Please provide properly formatted code - now the methods in `HospitalService` appear inside the constructor.

Comment: can u suppor me by comming to my any desk account it a bit long code

Comment: I know you've got Maven set up, can you verify that the Eclipse project settings have it compiling for Java 1.8 like you've declared in the pom, and not something higher than Java 11?

Also, Eclipse has a built-in formatter. By default, you invoke it with Ctrl/Cmd+Shift+F. And which one's are the 4 rest dependencies?